# best flash video player for mobile website

Tags: flash, video, mobile-website

What is the best flash video player to use for a mobile website? I'm using flowplayer for my desktop site, and need to find a way to get the same videos playing on mobile. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to provide a H.264 "fallback" when no flash is installed.  Thats what most sites are already doing on the web.  It looks like the way to go.

Search the web for "html5 video tag" or similar to see the way to get this working.

Official W3C documentation: [4.8.6 The video element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html)
Wikipedia with some discussion of the video formats supported: [HTML5 video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video)